# How a compiler identifies that there is a checked exception

Tags: java

In Java, how a compiler will identify that there is a checked exception? I mean how it is identifying it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right from the docs:

> A compiler for the Java programming language checks, at compile time,
>   that a program contains handlers for checked exceptions, by analyzing
>   which checked exceptions can result from execution of a method or
>   constructor. For each checked exception which is a possible result,
>   the throws clause for the method (§8.4.6) or constructor (§8.8.5) must
>   mention the class of that exception or one of the superclasses of the
>   class of that exception. This compile-time checking for the presence
>   of exception handlers is designed to reduce the number of exceptions
>   which are not properly handled.
>
> The unchecked exceptions classes are the class RuntimeException and
>   its subclasses, and the class Error and its subclasses. All other
>   exception classes are checked exception classes. The Java API defines
>   a number of exception classes, both checked and unchecked. Additional
>   exception classes, both checked and unchecked, may be declared by
>   programmers. See §11.5 for a description of the exception class
>   hierarchy and some of the exception classes defined by the Java API
>   and Java virtual machine.

So basically it looks at the code, if it comes across an exception, looks up the inheritance hierarchy of the exception to decide  if it is checked or unchecked.

[Read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/exceptions.html)

Answer (score 1):

All checked exceptions have a base class `Exception`, while non checked exceptions extend `RuntimeException` or `Error`.

Comment: There's also the potential for other subclasses of Throwable which are none of Exceptions, RuntimeExceptions, nor Errors.

Comment: All Throwable are checked, except Error and RuntimeException. If you subclass Throwable directly it is checked.

Comment: There are unchecked exceptions which satisfy both your conditions.